# Creating Column with Desired Content in Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create expressions like Ali 53 under the Plate Student column. But I get the Length of values does not match length of index error. How can I do what I want?

[image: Data Frame]

```
import pandas as pd  #library import
oki=pd.read_csv("exams.csv") #file reading

values=pd.array([53,6,1,12,34,19]) #plate numbers
oki["Plaka"]=[""+ str(i)  for i in values] #for iteration




c=oki["Index"]=oki["Öğrenciler"]  #Öğrenci=student, plaka=plate
"""
c  
Out[35]: 
0        Ali
1      Kerem
2       Sami
3      Bahar
4        Gül
5    Mustafa
Name: Öğrenciler, dtype: object
"""

oki["Plaka Ögrenci"]=[i+ str(j) for i in  oki["Index"] for j in oki["Plaka"] ] #nested for iteration
#Creating Column with Desired Content in Python Data Frame
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve]. What are `[""+ str(i)  for i in values]` and `c=oki["Index"]=oki["Öğrenciler"]` meant to do? Have you looked at the Pandas docs?

Comment: I added  a screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLHhO.png ) İ am using c=oki["Index"]=oki["Öğrenciler"] to achieve Student's names according to the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oki["Plaka>Ögrenci"]= oki['Öğrenciler'].map(str) + '-' + oki['Plaka'].map(str)
```